# How can I resolve Workspace Dependencies with Nuxeo in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nuxeo

I several Maven projects in my Eclipse Workspace.

Project A is a dependency for Project B.

Project B is a Nuxeo project. it means that all the dependencies for project B should be defined in Nuxeo.

Each time I change something in project A, I should rebuild a jar a deploy somewhere (defined in Preferences -> Nuxeo -> User librairies).

Is there a quicker way ?
**Can I resolve my workspace dependencies with a Nuxeo project, like I do for a Maven project ?**

Comment: You will have to build it everytime you do changes. i prefer is to use a parent / aggregator module which will contain entries for your 2 projects. It will have a packaging of type pom. This parent module will simply call / execute the poms for both your modules. This way, when any module changes, you just have to run this parent pom, instead of building each module separately. The parent pom will take care of building the child modules (Project A and Project B in your case). Check this [link](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/) for and example.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of : after each change I should run "mvn clean install".   

Ok, I can skip tests, but still I should rebuild after each rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution :

I should remove the lib from Nuxeo libs (Preferences -> Nuxeo -> User librairies).

And I shoul add the project A to project B's buildpath :
right click on project -> buildpath -> configure -> Projects -> add.

And Tada, Eclipse resolve my dependences as basic Java project.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're using Nuxeo IDE. Please detail the versions for Eclipse, Nuxeo IDE and Nuxeo SDK.

The "User libraries" data is used to help the Nuxeo IDE to map a JAR with its Maven GAV. This allows to provide advanced features like POM completion (sync), JAR discovery, class suggestion...

> Can I resolve my workspace dependencies with a Nuxeo project, like I do for a Maven project?

Yes, you can: it is still possible to reference other projects in the Java build path (ie reference A from B). You may need to check the option "`Do not use SDK classpath container (for experts only)`" in `Preferences / Nuxeo / Nuxeo SDK`.
I guess that the only draw back is that you will have to manage yourselves the deployment of that library into the target server.